# React native launch crash

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, ios-simulator, react-native-ios

I'm beginner in react native and I'm working on a project. From last week, I'm facing app crashing issue which is happening randomly and few times on ios app relaunching.

This issue is happening on iOS device as well as on simulator. I'm using XCode version 12.3 and simulator is iPhone 11 14.3.

RN version :- 16.13.1

After debugging a lot, I found that issue log as below :

```
assertion failed: 19G2021 18C61: libxpc.dylib + 50260 [056A93711C2C- 
385B-BB06-F099DE20E73A]: 
0x7d
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.E75323CB-1B86-4E05-A064- 
C11CBA793737[32560] (UIKitApplication:(package name)[23fb][rb- 
legacy] 
[35121]): Service exited due to SIGABRT
```

If anyone knows this solution, please help me.

Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance for your time and support.

Comment: Which iOS simulator are you using? What is the version of your react-native? What is the version of your XCode? Please provide more details of your env.

Comment: Yeah, updated all details.

Comment: Hi Mohammed, Did you find any solution?